# Service in symfony bundle depends on service in application

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, autowired, symfony-bundle

I am creating a Symfony 6 bundle that provides a service that depends on the utilizing application to implement a provided interface as a service. This bundle provides a service called `MyBundleService`. It also provides an interface called `MyBundleManagerInterface` that is expected to be implemented as a service by any utilizing applications.

How to auto-inject the service that utilizing applications implement into the `MyBundleService` service that my bundle provides?

Here is some simplified code to illustrate:

First is the interface:

```php
/** MyBundleManagerInterface.php **/
namespace MyCompany\MyBundle\Interface;

interface MyBundleManagerInterface
{
    public function processRequest(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request): void;
}
```

Now, let say an application implements `MyBundleManagerInterface` as a service:

```php
namespace App\Service;
use MyCompany\MyBundle\Interface\MyBundleManagerInterface;

class ManagerService implements MyBundleManagerInterface {

    public function processRequest(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request): void 
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

The service `MyBundleService` inside my bundle seems to not be able to get the `MyBundleManagerInterface` implementation, which is the service `ManagerService` from the application.

```php
/** MyBundleService.php **/
// the bundle has been configured to autowire all classes inside this namespace
namespace MyCompany\MyBundle\Service; 
use MyCompany\MyBundle\Interface\MyBundleManagerInterface;

class MyBundleService
{
    public function __construct(protected ?MyBundleManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        // the injected $manager seems to be NULL here
    }

    #[Required]
    public function setManager(?MyBundleManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        // this Required-attributed method is called, yet the $manager parameter is NULL
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

}
```

What did I miss? Is there a way to tell Symfony dependency injection that the `ManagerService` from the application can be injected into `MyBundleService`? Or is it not possible for a bundle to use services from applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Symfony doesn't know which class to implement because you can implement the interface more than one times.
To know wich class to autowire you must set an alias to the interface.

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    MyCompany\MyBundle\Interface\MyBundleManagerInterface: '@App\Service\ManagerService'
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces

For this use case I prefer to use tagged services. Then you can use more than one implementation and avoid requiring changes to the services.yaml file.

```
#[AutoconfigureTag('app.your.tag')]
interface MyBundleManagerInterface
{
    public function doSomething(): void;
}
```

```
class MyBundleService
{
    public function __construct(
        #[TaggedIterator('app.your.tag')]
        private readonly iterable $manager,
    ) {
    }

    public function run(): void
    {
        foreach ($ths->manager as $manager) {
            $manager->doSomething();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The interface aliasing in the `services.yaml` is just what I needed. Thanks! Also +1 for mentioning the tagged services annotation method.